# Display awarded bounty in android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties, android-app

One of [my answers](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/338/is-there-any-app-for-stack-exchange/50738#50738) over https://android.stackexchange.com/ has been awarded 100 rep bounty but it's not being displayed in the android app.

I think it should be displayed as part of the question/answer details.

> > [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the report. This was an oversight which has been fixed for version 1.0.10:

[image]

Comment: Yeah It's resolved. Thanks